# XPath retrieve values hierarchy

Tags: xpath, xml2

Having an XML document

```
<A id="first">
  <B id="second">
    <C id="third">
    <C id="fourth">
  </B>
  <B id="fifth">
    <C id="sixth">
  </B>
  <B id="seventh">
    ...
</A>
```

how can I list possible combinations of `id` attributes while maintaining node hierarchy in the response?

```
first,second,third
first,second,fourth
first,fifth,sixth
...
```

Eventually I'd like to execute the query over PostgreSQL database hosted XML document through `XML2` extension [1], such that individual lines could be `unnest`ed into table rows

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(xpath_list(<column>, '<query>', ','), ','))
FROM <table>
```

yielding a table similar to

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | second | third |
| first | second | fourth |
| first | fifth | sixth |

Not sure it's even possible through XPath as I was not able to find any relevant documentation but would like to consult the approach with comunity before I abandon the idea

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xml2.html

Answer (score 0):

XPath 3.1:

```
//C!string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/@id, ',') => string-join(codepoints-to-string(10))
```

gives a single string

```
first,second,third
first,second,fourth
nfirst,fifth,sixth
```